# How can I change favicon in Bootstrap based agency theme

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, favicon

Agency free theme in Bootstrap comes a long with GitHub favicon, I cannot track where the GitHub favicon comes from and that's why I can't change it. It didn't override the starting favicon when I added my custom favicon between `<head></head>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this way. and go to [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp)

```html
<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' sizes="16x16" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a cache problem... try to force the favicon refresh using the link tag and a querystring on your filename.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico" />
```

You can also try reloading with no cache (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd>) or restarting the browser

Answer (score 1):

For example, remove parts of code for your project.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="/img/image.png">
```